# Unexpected year on creating date from japanese Calendar

Tags: swift, date, calendar

```
let dateComponent = DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 12, day: 30)
print(Calendar(identifier: .japanese).date(from: dateComponent))

4040-12-29 17:00:00 +0000
```

Is there any idea why the returned date's year is 4040? Thanks

I'm assuming there is a different year format, but I don't find any information about it.

Comment: My bad I forget to mention that I run that code in Japanese Calendar system on devices.

Answer (score 0):

Working backwards I just checked:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .japanese)
let year = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.year], from: date)
// year == 4
```

Comparing with https://groups.oist.jp/resource-center/japanese-year-converter that looks correct. I bet that during day to day usage of dates Japanese folks use a Gregorian calendar as well. Seems like maybe this is used for official government documents and such?

EDIT:
Yea looks like according to https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calendar the Gregorian calendar is used. In general you'd be using `Calendar.current` for any sort of date display / input from the user, so as long as no assumptions are made about the calendar and storage in the backend / data layer is in a format that accounts for this information you'd be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
let formate = DateFormatter()
formate.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .japanese)
formate.dateFormat = "G y"
print(formate.string(from: Date()))
```

Try above code.

Comment: It's best to avoid code-only answers. Please provide (in your answer, not in a comment) an explanation of what what wrong with the code in the question and explain how your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when we create a DateComponent(year: 2022) in the Japanese Calendar System (device's calendar), the recognized year is Reiwa 2022, not 2022 in the current year.

That why's the returned date is on 4040 because Reiwa 2022 in the current year is 4040.

Thanks for answering.